# How to join pthread which ended from array of running pthread

Tags: c++, server, pthreads

I have a chat server written in c++ and i have a problem with phtreads.
This server suppose to handle multiple connections so i created array of pthread. when a new client connects it gives one pthread to this client from the array and it calls handle function where is comunication inplemented. but when this client disconect i dont know how to find which pthread ended and which index to a pthread array is empty. i know this code is horrible but i really want to make this program better

so my question is that can i do it this way that when one pthread ends i will empty that index to array of pthread for potencial next client conected in and when more that lets say 100 people connect i will realloc the array ?

how do i find which pthread ended for joining that pthread and for finding which index is now free to use again ?

```
struct parsing{
     int socket;
};

int i = 0;
int strop = 100;
pthread_t *thread;
thread = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*100);
struct parsing args;
while (1)
{
    if((client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&socket_addr, (socklen_t *)&client_sock_len)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Accept Error");
        return 5;
    }
    printf("connected %d",client_sock);
    args.socket = client_sock;
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &handle_connection, (void *)&args);
    i++;
    if (i == strop)
    {
        strop = strop + 100;
        void * ptr = (pthread_t*)realloc(thread,sizeof(pthread_t)*strop);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use std::thread.

Answer (score 0):

> how do i find which pthread ended for joining that pthread and for finding which index is now free to use again ?

The pthreads API does not provide a way to discover terminated threads.  Glibc has has a non-portable extension by which you can attempt a non-blocking join of a specific thread (see `pthread_tryjoin_np()`), and if that's available to you then you could build a polling-based solution around it.

But I'd say the *right* way to accomplish this is to establish a mechanism for worker threads to *tell* the main thread that they are done.  For instance, they might add their own thread ID to a linked list that the main thread can also see, and then send a signal or use `pthread_cond_signal()` to get the main thread's attention.  Do be sure to provide proper synchronization for multi-threaded access to shared variables.

Comment: The re-use of the args struct for several pthreads will almost certainly lead to problems, Even if you copy the file descriptor immediately within your thread. It is always possible that another client connects before the new thread is scheduled by the OS. (as John said: proper synchronisation is crucial)